# How to refer columns in Power Query by index or position?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a line as below in Power Query. So instead of referring it by name, I want it by position dynamically. Can someone help here, please

```
#"Filtered Part Desc" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns3", each
                            Text.Contains([part_desc], "ENG") or
                            Text.Contains([part_desc], "TRANS"))
```

I tried replacing `[part_desc]` by `Table.ColumnNames(Promoted){6}`, but it is not working

Comment: Can you explain the logic of what you are trying to do? I don't understand what your intended goal is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `Table.ColumnNames(MyTable){n}` to return a column name by its position - this this is base 0, so the 6th column name would be `Table.ColumnNames(MyTable){5}`

You can then use `Record.Field` to reference a column by its name.

You can also filter by a list, rather than stringing criteria together with the `or` operator.

So, putting this together for your example:

```
    #"Filtered Part Desc" = Table.SelectRows ( 
        #"Removed Columns3", 
        each List.Contains(
            {"ENG","TRANS"}, 
            Record.Field(_, Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns3"){5})
        )
    )
```