# How to index values in a table in PowerBI?

Tags: indexing, powerbi

Just have a very simple question on how to index a value in PowerBI, suppose I have the following data set loaded.

[image]

Now, suppose I want the value 55 from the alert status column.  Index wise (starting from 0), it would be (4, 2).  What is the easiest way to select value 55?  For example, in Python, I can go Table[4, 2].

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113354/how-to-refer-columns-in-power-query-by-index-or-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a DAX expression that returns the scalar value 55.

```
CALCULATE (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Alert Status] ),
    'Table'[Status] = 4
)
```

You can quickly examine this by clicking **New Table** in the **Modeling** tab, and copy & pasting the following formula.

```
Test = ADDCOLUMNS (
    ROW ( "Status to Lookup", 4 ),
    "Result",
    VAR StatusToLookup = [Status to Lookup]
    RETURN CALCULATE (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Alert Status] ),
        'Table'[Status] = StatusToLookup
    )
)
```

[image: Output]