# How to select certain column in power query

Tags: powerquery, m

I would like to choose a certain columns in power query, but not using their names. Ex. I can do this in R, by command: select. I'm wondering how i can do it in power query. I found some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113354/how-to-refer-columns-in-power-query-by-index-or-position/64400204#64400204), but not all that I need.

Any idea, if I want to refer to more than one column?

It doesn't work if I write the code as below:

```
#"Filtered Part Desc" = Table.SelectRows ( 
#"Removed Columns3", 
each List.Contains(
    { "ENG", "TRANS" }, 
    Record.Field(_, Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns3") { 5, 6, 7 }) 
)
)
```

Comment: Do you want to just select certain columns or are you also trying to simultaneously do filtering logic on those columns at the same time using the same rule on each like in the linked post?

Comment: i've tried to refer to those columns to do unpivot or change type.
i can't do it by using unpivot other columns or etc, becasue each time i have a different columns names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I have this table and want to do a couple of things to it.

[image: Source table]

First, I want to change the column type of the second and last columns. We can use `Table.ColumnNames` to do this using simple indexing (which starts at zero) as follows:

```
Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source,
    {
        {Table.ColumnNames(Source){1}, Int64.Type},
        {Table.ColumnNames(Source){3}, Int64.Type}
    }
)
```

That works but requires specifying each index separately. If we want to unpivot these columns like this

```
Table.Unpivot(#"Changed Type", {"Col2", "Col4"}, "Attribute", "Value")
```

but using the index values instead we can use the same method as above

```
Table.Unpivot(
    #"Changed Type", 
    {
        Table.ColumnNames(Source){1},
        Table.ColumnNames(Source){3}
    }, "Attribute", "Value"
)
```

But is there a way to do this where we can use a single list of positional index values and use `Table.ColumnNames` only once? I found a relatively simple though unintuitive method on [this blog](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/01/24/list-selectpositions-in-power-bi-and-power-query/). For this case, it works as follows:

```
Table.Unpivot(
    #"Changed Type",
    List.Transform({1,3}, each Table.ColumnNames(Source){_}),
    "Attribute", "Value"
)
```

This method starts with the list of positional index values and then transforms them into column names by looking up the names of the columns corresponding to those positions.

---

Here's the full M code for the query I was playing with:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSlTSUTIE4nIgtlSK1YlWSgKyjIC4AogtwCLJQJYxEFcCsTlYJAXIMgHiKiA2U4qNBQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Col1 = _t, Col2 = _t, Col3 = _t, Col4 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{Table.ColumnNames(Source){1}, Int64.Type},{Table.ColumnNames(Source){3}, Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Changed Type", List.Transform({1,3}, each Table.ColumnNames(Source){_}), "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Columns"
```